# jQuery : find out whether the element is of block, inline-block or inline display

Tags: jquery, css, block, inline

Is there a way to find out whether the css 'display' property of the element is set to 'block', 'inline-block' or 'inline' using jQuery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try using

```
$('.myelem').css('display');
```

this will return the value of any CSS property ( display in your case ). Mind that if you use it for other purposes, it will also contain units ( eg `.css('width')` might return `33px` or `50%` depending on what is declared in your CSS)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
var block = $('.mydiv').css('display');
```

here is a full working example on fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/v73XD/

You can read any css property or set css property using the `css method`. You can read more about it here in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/).